# SQL Server 2005 and Datanucleus problem (ntext query)

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, sql-server-2005, datanucleus

Started getting errors with SQL Server 2005

This is the first time i've tested our app with Datanucleus 2.x (last test was made with DN 1.x)

I use Eclipse RCP.

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPrepared
Statement.java:390)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:340)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java
:283)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.SQLController.executeStatementQuery(SQLController.java:463)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery.performExecuteInternal(JDOQLQuery.java:755)
... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first line mentions, you are trying to do a DISTINCT on a result set that has ntext type fields inside it .. this is not possible..

have a look at [Is there any way to DISTINCT or group by a text (or ntext) in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028061/is-there-any-way-to-distinct-or-group-by-a-text-or-ntext-in-sql-server-2005) for possible solution. (*cast the field to nvarchar(max)*)