# SQL Distinct - Not working

Tags: sql, distinct

i have 3 tables: Student, Apply, and College.

And I want to return the student and the major for each student. How ever, when i do this, i get "duplicates". So i said: let's use distinct, however with distinct i get an error, while if i take off "distinct" the query works fine (but with duplicates).

I have tried using this code without `distinct`, but i get the same results. Please help.

*This is MS SQL SERVER ENTERPRISE 2008.
*I get duplicated students... for example in rows 1 and 3, i get the same: Student:"Amy", Major: "CS".

```
select **distinct** SName as Student, major  
from Student, Apply  
where Student.sID = Apply.sID;
```

Comment: Search for sql joins.

Comment: what kind of duplicate row do you get?

Comment: In row 1 and 3, i get: Student = Amy, and Major = CS :/

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028061/is-there-any-way-to-distinct-or-group-by-a-text-or-ntext-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the data type of the column to varchar for distinct to work: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), column).`

try:

```
select distinct CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), SName), CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), major)
from Student, Apply  
where Student.sID = Apply.sID;
```

Comment: I have read that text is not going to be used anymore. I'm planning on using: nvarchar ;)

Comment: that would probably work too. Though if no other code uses this database it would be better to change the column type in database and use the SQL statement you used in the first place. (for performance and readability reasons)

Comment: This have worked!!! Thanks man! I dont get it full, but i'm gonna look for "Varchar(max). Would you explain why with text it does not work?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't use MSSQL but I suppose text is some kind of a binary field that MSSQL doesn't know how to handle for comparison of values very good.

Comment: Hi @Spikolynn,  i have now created new tables with the "nvarchar" (what is it? I don't know how to call it, total newbie on SQL). How ever, when y apply my **initial query**, i get the same problem. The data type text cannnot be comparable... I need to still convert it? (Varchar?)... and 2) When to use "max" or for example (50)??? Thanks man!

This is how i have created the tables: 

**create table Student(sID int, sName nvarchar(50), GPA real, sizeHS int );**

Comment: hi, you also create 'major' column as nvchar ?

Comment: I haven't :/ sorry. I did and now my original code works. Thanks to you man. One final question: When one should use nvarchar(max) vs nvarchar(number)? What are best practices? Thanks a lot, again!

Comment: If you know data in field is for instance 20 char long at most, then use 20. If you don't know how long it is, use max to be sure. Max is around 4k i think.
There may be some issues with multibyte character sets but you'd have to experiment with that.