# Union Causing The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries (comprised of some temp tables) that i want to union together. When I comment out one (doesn't matter which) of the queries with the union out, it works. But when i introduce the union, I get `The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.`
I don't understand why since neither of the main queries use a distinct. Heres the main select for reference:

```
SELECT  
    dbo.CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM AS 'Account Number',
    dbo.CUSTTABLE.NAME AS 'Customer Name',
    [DESCRIPTION] AS 'Division',
    ISNULL(dbo.USERINFO.NAME, 'OPEN') AS 'Sales Engineer',
    [STATE],
    PHONE,
    PAYMTERMID AS 'Terms',
    (CASE BLOCKED
        WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Financial Hold'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'System Hold'
        ELSE 'Unknown' END) AS 'Status',
    [45-60],
    [61-90],
    [91-120],
    [120+],
    #temptable2.Today,
    ISNULL(USERMEMO, '') AS 'Notes',
    ISNULL(#temptable2.Today / NULLIF((ISNULL(#salesTemp.PQ1, 0) / 90), 0),0) AS 'DSO1',
    CustTable.StatisticsGroup as 'Past Due Category'

FROM
    dbo.CUSTTABLE INNER JOIN 
    dbo.DIMENSIONS ON DIMENSION2_ = NUM INNER JOIN
    #temptable2 ON dbo.CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM = #temptable2.ACCOUNTNUM LEFT OUTER JOIN
    #temptable ON dbo.CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM = #temptable.ACCOUNTNUM LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.SMMSALESUNITMEMBERS ON SALESGROUP = SALESUNITID AND SALESMANAGER = 1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.USERINFO ON ID = SALESMANID AND [ENABLE] = 1    
    JOIN #salesTemp on #salesTemp.ACCOUNTNUM = CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM
WHERE
    DIMENSION2_ IN (@division)

UNION
SELECT 
    Customer_ID AS 'Account Number',
    Customer_Name AS 'Customer Name',
    'South Bend' AS Division,
    '' AS 'Sales Engineer',
    'Indiana' AS 'State',
    '' AS 'Phone',
    Customer_Terms AS 'Terms',
    '' AS 'Status',
    [45-60],
    [61-90],
    [91-120],
    [120+],
    [Today],
    '' AS 'Notes',
    '' AS 'DSO1',
    '' AS 'Past Due Category'
FROM #temptable4
```

Comment: A union by default applies a distinct which isn't supported with ntext. Try `UNION ALL` (it doesn't do a distinct) to see if it gets past the problem.  If it does, then look at the data types for each of the fields are any `ntext`?  If it is, you may need to cast the value into nvarchar(max) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c836eda3-f969-4ec2-a231-b2930e288ad5/select-distinct-with-ntext-fields or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028061/is-there-any-way-to-distinct-or-group-by-a-text-or-ntext-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: Union all Gives me 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.' at the same spot. The datatypes are all either char or varchar for the character fields

Comment: Data types for: #temptable2.Today, #salesTemp.PQ1, enable, salesmanager?  May also be the `'' AS 'DSO1',` I'm not sure if SQL server treats empty string null, and thus can't convert to numeric  may need to do `NULL AS 'DSO1'` instead...  Infact... I bet it being this last part.

Comment: Ack i got the union all to work. stupid error. i needed to put a 0 in the bottom "DSO1" spot. lame

Comment: Careful you don't need the union all now.  I only did that to eliminate the ntext as being the issue, and the engine returned a better, more descriptive error... So do you want ALL records or just distinct? If just distinct, use union, if all records from both, union all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change: `'' AS 'DSO1',` 
to 
`NULL as 'DS01',`

Empty set can't be converted to numeric in SQL server; which is required based on the datatype defined in the top select of the union.

I assume this is the problem because the top select in the union will return a numeric value.  Since empty set can't be cast to a number, either provide a number (0) or use null.

Keep in mind when executing a union the number of columns must match and their data types must match.  If they don't you get errors such as this.

As to the comment, "I don't understand why since neither of the main queries use a distinct"  A `UNION` executes a distinct on the resulting unioned results.  `UNION ALL` will not.  This is why execution of a `UNION ALL` performs faster, as it doens't have to do the duplicate removal contained within the execution of a `UNION`.